Why are the top of the F/A-18 strakes curved?


As seen in this picture, the top of the strake has a slight curve to it. I'm mainly talking about the curve seen if you were to look at it straight on.
To be more clear, not the curve of the strake as you travel down the airframe, but the downward curve if looked at from the side or front. Basically where the strake attaches to the airframe is at a higher point than where it ends. (Not the best picture for this, but it's the best I could find)
Is there any aerodynamic reason for this, or is it just how the airframe was built?
If I'm correct, the curve would raise the pressure on top of the strake, as a curved surface would be closer to the freestream air.

Wyatt, please do not continue to make small edits to your question, bumping it to the top of the "active questions" list with each one. That's considered poor form and can have adverse consequences.

@RalphJ Sorry about that, probably should've edited everything at once.

The airflow at some point over the top of a wing that is close to a fuselage will not necessarily be in the exact direction of flight. You would then expect the strake orientation to be finessed to follow the airflow, so as to minimize yawing forces and drag.
Now note that strakes are commonly used to correct the direction of airflow over the wing, so as to minimize turbulence propagation into the airflow over the tail surfaces at large angles of attack. God and the computational fluid dynamicists only know what the spanwise airflow distribution is under those conditions, and whether or not the strake requires being set at an angle to the direction of flight to ensure its effectiveness.
As always, Peter Kämpf knows the right answer and your mileage will be lower in California.
